# Invoking a button in a form from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms, Form1 and Form 2. I need to access a button in Form1 from Form2 in order to refresh the datagridview in Form1

this is Form1:

```
private void BookLoad()
    {
        DataSet d = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select * from Books  ", cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        da.Fill(d, "Books");
        dataGridView2.DataSource = d;
        dataGridView2.DataMember = "Books";

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Issue where StudentNumber LIKE @number", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", textBox1.Text);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds, "Issue");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Issue";

        DataSet dss = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select Books_Borrowed,Date_Borrowed,Return_Date,Quantity from Issue where StudentNumber = @number", cn);
        cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", textBox1.Text);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdd);
        da.Fill(dss, "Issue");
        dataGridView3.DataSource = dss;
        dataGridView3.DataMember = "Issue";

    }


   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Form2 form = new Form2();
      form.Show();
    }


    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       BookLoad();
       MessageBox.Show();
    }
```

I need to access button10 from Form2

Comment: What action in `Form2` you would like to use to trigger `button10` in from1?

Comment: when i click a button in Form 2 it will do some stuff and insert something to the database and then hides itself. I need to access button10 to refresh Form 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that `Form2` is some kind of an editing dialog. It is *really* shouldn't have access to controls on `Form1`.

Much simpler thing is to open `Form2` as modal using `ShowDialog()` method (using `Show` method you can open multiple `Form2` when click `button2` many times)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form2 form = new Form2();
  DialogResult r = form.ShowDialog();
  if (r == DialogResult.OK)
  {
      BookLoad();
      MessageBox.Show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, be little cautious in playing with `Hide()` and `Show()`, few things might not work as expected when form is invisible.

An ideal solution to achieve the functionality, define an event in `Form2` and subscribe to that event in `Form1`

Declare a delegate in `Form2` as specified (Keep this logic in `Form2`)

```
public delegate void Listen(object sender, EventArgs args);

// Expose the event off your component
public event Listen ListenChange;
```

Keep this logic inside `Button_Click` event in `Form2`, just before hiding the form.

```
// And to raise it
if (ListenChange != null)
{
   ListenChange(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Now in `Form1` subscribe to this event and raise change.

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.ListenChange += (s, ev) => button10.PerformClick();
form.Show();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a good approach but if you wanted to do this add a static function in Form1:

```
public static void btnDown(){
    SomeButton.Invoke();
}
```

Now call this function from Form2 like

```
Form1.btnDown();
```